# Do "Civil Aviation Regulations" and "Aeronautics Bulletins" still have any legal authority today?

Tags: faa-regulations, aviation-history

[This is a history of the FAA from their site.](https://www.faa.gov/about/media/b-chron.pdf)

In the U.S., we had the original set of aviation laws known as aeronautical bulletins back in the 1920's and 1930's. Later (in 1938) we had the Civil Aviation Regulations (CARs), created by the Civil Aeronautics Authority (CAA), added to them.

I am curious if those laws were actually repealed or simply made redundant by today's regulations and whether or not there were additional laws not seen in the FARs today but which did exist in the CARs and Aeronautical Bulletins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many aircraft were certified to CAR standards.  Those aircraft still have to meet those standard.  Even a brand new aircraft off the line today, that is produced  based on a type certificate data sheet that has CAR regulations has to meet those regulations.

Comment: Great addition!  I didn't think about that.

Comment: Where is the source of this rule?  I searched a little bit, but I'm not finding it.

Comment: Take a look at a type certificate data sheet, and it includes the certification basis in it.  Typically there are multiple basis with specific regulations called out.  For example the 727 is a CAR 4b aircraft, with a few exemptions http://www.airweb.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgMakeModel.nsf/0/5d48fc77a31b7f6985256722006b0c1c/$FILE/A3we.pdf

Answer (score 6):

No, except for a type certification rule.

> Aug 23, 1958:
>
> President Eisenhower signed the Federal Aviation Act of 1958 (P.L.
>   85-726) into law. Treating comprehensively the Federal role in
>   fostering and regulating civil aeronautics and air commerce, the new
>   statute repealed the Air Commerce Act of 1926, the Civil Aeronautics
>   Act of 1938, the Airways Modernization Act of 1957, and those portions
>   of the various Presidential reorganization plans dealing with civil
>   aviation.

The aviation law slate was wiped clean and started fresh with the FAA, although many of the principles in the aeronautical bulletins and the Civil Aviation Regulations were clearly incorporated into the FARs we know today.

Comment: In a way it's a yes, if you see an old bulletin there's a good chance it means there a reg somewhere.